# Is it possible to develop a create-react-app on a vps?

Tags: reactjs, digital-ocean, vps

I basically want to start developing a create-react-app on a vps so that my client can check my progress.

I know you can "Add React to a Website" but I want to use libraries in my website and I don't know how to do that with the "Add React to an existing website" tutorial on the ReactJS site.

Edit: Adding more tags.

Comment: yes you can use create-react-app on a vps. all create-react-app does is scaffold some files / folders. everything after the initial command is just normal react app with a dev server and a command to build the website. if you're okay with it being open source then you might want to do something like https://www.netlify.com/ which would be a million times easier. also, you should be using create-react-app locally... then on the vps pulling the git repository and building, instead of developing directly on the vps, but that's a personal preference since I want to code in vscode / atom not vim

Comment: Is it possible to have it run on the vps without building it.
Edit: corrected my phrasing.

Comment: you can build it locally and push the pre-built contents to the vps server sure. not sure what the point of that is though. that is, you can build it anywhere.. like as part of your CI process, then drop the build files on wherever you want, like on your server

Comment: Sorry, my wording was wrong. Is it possible to have the website run on the vps without having to build it at all?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean.. if you don't build it, then there is no website

Comment: are you asking if you can run the dev server on the vps? sure you can do that

Comment: Exactly, could you please explain how? I can't find out how to do it. (If you could link me to a page that explains it that would, of course, be great too.)

Comment: it's exactly the same way you would do it on your computer locally. `npm start` ?

Comment: But what ipadress would I use to vieuw the page? just the public ip of the vps?

Comment: the dev server runs on `http://localhost:3000` though you can change the port via `PORT=<whatever>`. so if you do `PORT=80 npm start` and your vps ip address is 1.2.3.4 then `http://1.2.3.4` will be your running dev server

Comment: I'm very sorry if I'm wrong I really appreciate your help but I don't understand. Your localhost isn't the same as your public ip right. If I run my react app on my own computer I can't access it from another device outside the network because it's running on my local ip.

Comment: localhost refers to the machine that the code is running on. If you run it on your computer then localhost means your computer. if you run it on your server then localhost means that server. if you opened your computers IP address on your modem / router, then your computer could be accessed via its IP address by other people on the internet. a VPS is just a computer that is configured to allow connections from other people, you can do the same thing with your computer if you want. not advisable of course, but to illustrate the point

Comment: Ok, sorry for my late response but I've tried to run in on my vps as you told me. When I start the react development server I on my vps it only shows "http://localhost:3000/" and not other ip. when i try to acces it via my servers public ip on port 3000 nothing happens.

Comment: it should say localhost on the vps since ITS local to itself. localhost IS the server. did you do `npm start` or `PORT=80 npm start`. try the latter and go to the ip address without a port. your vps might not be configured to forward on anything other than port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Why not use a service like ngrok
- you can use your own laptop or server
- [ngrok - secure introspectable tunnels to localhost](https://ngrok.com/)
- so after you create and start your react app

  ```
  npx create-react-app my-app
  cd my-app
  npm start
  ```

[image]

- [signup / ngrok - secure introspectable tunnels to localhost](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/user/signup)
- Then run

  ```
  ngrok http 3000 -host-header="localhost:3000"
  ```

[image]

- open the url fom any where in the internet

[image]